# How is the tracking of the event of click on push notification and opening of messages in inbox(Mobile Push)?

Tags: mobilepush, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

How does salesforce mobile push track events for opening push notifications and opening messages in inbox?
We are sending several push notifications to thousands of people and we are noticing the opening rate is very low. We did internal tests and some notifications/messages that we open are not being shown in the salesforce dashboard.

[image]

the sdk is started with the following code:

[image]

Comment: You're conflating multiple things in your question. Push notifications are not inbox messages. Also, was your test on iOS, Android, or both? Finally, Inbox Messaging is not supported in the React Native plugin. If you're looking for inbox message opened reporting it could be your implementation. Please open a support request.

Comment: @BillMote the tests were both on Android and IOS. It was necessary to create a native module to support the inbox in react native, but the point here is how mobile push tracks click events in push notifications and messages in the inbox?

Comment: If you call `track` it will be tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Mobile Push tracks events such as push notification openings and message openings in the Salesforce Mobile app by using a combination of server-side logging and client-side analytics. When a push notification is sent, the Salesforce Mobile SDK logs the notification on the server and associates it with the recipient's device. When the recipient opens the notification, the SDK logs the event on the device and sends the information back to the server for reporting.

The accuracy of these events depends on several factors, including the reliability of the push notification service, the configuration of the app, and the recipient's device and network settings. If your organization is experiencing a low opening rate, there could be several reasons why the events are not being accurately reported in the Salesforce dashboard, such as:

- Incorrect configuration of the app
- Network connectivity issues
- Recipient's device settings that prevent push notifications from being received or opened

To improve the accuracy of the events, you may want to consider the following:

- Check the app configuration to ensure that it's set up correctly and that the appropriate events are being logged
- Monitor the recipient's network connectivity to ensure that the device is connected to the internet when the notifications are being sent
- Check the recipient's device settings to make sure that push notifications are enabled and that the app has permission to receive them

It's also a good idea to test the app on multiple devices and networks to identify any issues and make any necessary changes.

Comment: to launch the salesforce mobile push sdk we are using following the react-native-marketingcloudsdk documentation, is there anything else in this startup that can contribute to improve the tracking of the open rate of push notifications?
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Comment: Yes, there are several steps you can take to improve the tracking of the open rate of push notifications when using the Salesforce Mobile Push SDK in a React Native app. Here are a few recommendations:

1) SDK initialization: Make sure that the SDK is initialized correctly and that the appropriate settings are configured. The SDK should be initialized as early as possible in the app's lifecycle, and the correct app ID and access token should be provided.

Comment: 2) Push notification settings: Verify that the push notification settings are configured correctly in the app, and that the recipient has granted permission for the app to receive push notifications.

3) Event tracking: Ensure that the appropriate events are being tracked and logged, such as push notification sent, delivered, and opened events.

4) Debugging: Use debugging tools and logs to identify any issues with the SDK, such as missing events or incorrect settings.

Comment: 5) Testing: Test the app on multiple devices and networks to identify any issues and to ensure that the events are being logged correctly.

By following these steps and regularly monitoring the tracking of push notification open rates, you should be able to identify any issues and improve the accuracy of the tracking.

Comment: all the steps you mentioned have already been done, including tests in production with people with different networks.Analyzing the logs does not show a failure either when starting the SDK or when the notification arrives and the user interacts with it

Comment: I added in my post the SDK initialization code, if you can check if in SDK initialization it is still necessary to add something

Comment: provide the SDK initialization code for further analysis

Comment: I added in my post the SDK initialization code, can you double check my post?

Comment: Many of these comments should be incorporated into the answer. I am concerned by the statement in the answer that the device needs to be online to receive the notification. If it is a push notification thay is wrong since the notification will be queued for delivery when the device is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `etAnalytics` enabled in your SDK configuration then you will get engagement analytics for notification opened, in app message displayed, geofence entered, etc.

Additionally, if you send an Alert+Inbox, then the "alert" is a push notification and will be tracked the same as any other notification.

With regards to Push Notifications, Inbox Messages, and InApp Messages, those are 3 discrete things and based on your question, I have no idea how to answer as you've intermixed them.

Comment: Focusing on the push notification, I notice a low retention of openings in the notifications even with Analytics enabled as sent by the `setAnalyticsEnabled(true)` notification.
Our team ran tests internally on Android and some notifications that had clicks are not being mapped.
Documentation where I got more information about how open notifications are counted: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_opens.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I have `"et_analytics": true` when called `logSdkState()`